# Python to transform rows to columns with delimeter, data contain *** need to delimit according to that

Tags: python

```
**START
IB    1107518415
BI    Paperback
BC    JHBC
CO    United Kingdom
ED    Alvarez, R. Michael
**
IB   0415836662
BI   Paperback
AU   Pituch, Keenan A.
AU    Stevens, James P.
BC   JHBC
CO   United Kingdom
EI    6 Rev ed
```

Please find above sample data, i need under IB->"1107518415" as first row and "0415836662" as second row and so on, please help me.

Comment: please edit such that the true input format is visible (hint: indent each line by 4 whitespaces)

Comment: Not clear: Do you want a list of all the numbers in lines starting with `IB`? Or do you want lists of lists grouped by `**`?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you want. If you want a list with the values in all the `IB` lines, try

```
res = [line.split(maxsplit=1)[1] for line in data.splitlines() if line.startswith("IB")]
# ['1107518415', '0415836662']
```

with `data` being a multi-line string holding your data. (Can also be a file, of course.) If you want to split the lines into groups separated by those `**`, you can use a `for` loop, appending to a nested list instead.

```
res = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    if line.startswith("**"):
        res.append([])
    else:
        res[-1].append(line.split(maxsplit=1)[1])
# [['1107518415', 'Paperback', 'JHBC', 'United Kingdom', 'Alvarez, R. Michael'],
#  ['0415836662', 'Paperback', 'Pituch, Keenan A.', 'Stevens, James P.', 'JHBC', 'United Kingdom', '6 Rev ed']]
```

Or as a "one-liner" using `itertools.groupby`, same result:

```
res = [[line.split(maxsplit=1)[1] for line in group] 
       for key, group in itertools.groupby(data.splitlines(), 
                                           key=lambda line: line.startswith("**")) 
       if key == False]
```

Comment: Thanks tobias, i have text file, need to convert that and later need to move to mysql table. Need to automate entire process.

Comment: @Sharath So, what is the question? Instead of `for line in data.splitlines():` just use `for line in yourfileobject:`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex (with `txt` having your example string):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'^\*\*.*\s+IB\s+(\d+)', txt, re.M)
['1107518415', '0415836662']
```

[Explanation of regex](https://regex101.com/r/QTjheA/1/)

---

Update based on comment:

If you want all the fields, say in a `dict`, you can still use a regex and a loop:

```
fl=[]
for m in re.finditer(r'^\*\*.*\s+([\s\S]+?)(?=^\*\*|\Z)', txt, re.M):
    di={}
    for s in m.group(1).splitlines():
        k,v=re.split(r'\s+', s, maxsplit=1)
        di[k]=v
    fl.append(di)
>>> fl
[{'ED': 'Alvarez, R. Michael', 'IB': '1107518415', 'CO': 'United Kingdom', 'BI': 'Paperback', 'BC': 'JHBC'}, {'EI': '6 Rev ed', 'BC': 'JHBC', 'BI': 'Paperback', 'AU': 'Stevens, James P.', 'CO': 'United Kingdom', 'IB': '0415836662'}]
```

Or, you can use a single compression:

```
>>> [{k:v for k, v in [re.split(r'\s+', s, maxsplit=1) for s in sl]} 
... for sl in 
... [e.splitlines() for e in re.findall(r'^\*\*.*\s+([\s\S]+?)(?=^\*\*|\Z)', txt, re.M)]]
[{'ED': 'Alvarez, R. Michael', 'IB': '1107518415', 'CO': 'United Kingdom', 'BI': 'Paperback', 'BC': 'JHBC'}, {'EI': '6 Rev ed', 'BC': 'JHBC', 'BI': 'Paperback', 'AU': 'Stevens, James P.', 'CO': 'United Kingdom', 'IB': '0415836662'}]
```

Comment: Thanks dawg for reply, not only for IB,need for all rows like BI,BC etc